# In scala can I pass repeated parameters to other methods?

Tags: scala, parameters, methods, variadic-functions

Here is something I can do in java, take the results of a repeated parameter and pass it to another method:

```
public void foo(String ... args){bar(args);}
public void bar(String ... args){System.out.println("count="+args.length);}
```

In scala it would look like this:

```
def foo(args:String*) = bar(args)
def bar(args:String*) = println("count="+args.length)
```

But this won't compile, the bar signature expects a series of individual strings, and the args passed in is some non-string structure.

For now I'm just passing around arrays.  It would be very nice to use starred parameters.  Is there some way to do it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Java makes an assumption that you want to automatically convert the Array `args` to varargs, but this can be problematic with methods that accept varargs of type Object.

Scala requires that you be explicit, by ascribing the argument with `: _*`.

```
scala> def bar(args:String*) = println("count="+args.length)
bar: (args: String*)Unit

scala> def foo(args:String*) = bar(args: _*)
foo: (args: String*)Unit

scala> foo("1", "2")
count=2
```

You can use `: _*` on any subtype of `Seq`, or on anything implicitly convertable to a `Seq`, notably `Array`.

```
scala> def foo(is: Int*) = is.length
foo: (is: Int*)Int

scala> foo(1, 2, 3)
res0: Int = 3

scala> foo(Seq(1, 2, 3): _*)
res1: Int = 3

scala> foo(List(1, 2, 3): _*)
res2: Int = 3

scala> foo(Array(1, 2, 3): _*)
res3: Int = 3

scala> import collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.JavaConversions._

scala> foo(java.util.Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3): _*)
res6: Int = 3
```

It is explained well with examples in the [Language Reference](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), in section 4.6.2.

Note that these examples are made with Scala 2.8.0.RC2.